# Retrieve selectBooleanButton element value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm currently working on a timetable project using JSF and Primefaces.
I'm struggling with p:selectBooleanButton, I want to call a method in the bean based on what the user checks:

```
<p:column>
    <p:selectBooleanButton id="token1" value="#{UserSession.getDisponibilitateGenerala(1)}"
        onLabel="Da" offLabel="Nu"
        onchange="#{UserSession.toogleDisponibilitateGenerala(1, value)}"/>
</p:column>
```

and my Bean:

```
public boolean getDisponibilitateGenerala(int token) {
    System.out.println("getDisponibilitateGenerala " + token);
    return utilizator.getDisponibiltateGenerala().contains((Integer) token);
}

public void toogleDisponibilitateGenerala(int token, boolean value) {
    //value alway comes false, no matter what is selected in the selectBooleanButton 
    System.out.println("toogleDisponibilitateGenerala " + token + " value: " + value);
    utilizator.getDisponibiltateGenerala().add((Integer) token);
}
```

Please note that I don't want to use regular beans since I have 200 Boolean cells that need populated, I opted for a token based logic. 
So the big question is how to call a onchange method with a int(the token id) and a boolean parameter based on the state of the p:selectBooleanButton

Comment: `onchange` is a client-side callback. It expects javascript as a value.

Comment: Use a `<p:ajax>` to call the method on `event="change"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `onchange` with `valueChangeListener`, for more information check the [PrimeFaces SelectBooleanButton documentation.](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/selectbooleanbutton)

Your column must look like this:

```
<p:column>
    <p:selectBooleanButton id="token1" value="#{UserSession.getDisponibilitateGenerala(1)}"
            onLabel="Da" offLabel="Nu"
            valueChangeListener="#{UserSession.toogleDisponibilitateGenerala(1, value)}"/>
</p:column>
```

Using the method above you will be able to `update` components only from the bean using `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("dataTable");`, so as [Mitchell Brooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8636108/mitchell-brooks) suggested in the comments, you can use a `<p:ajax>` like this:

```
<p:column>
    <p:selectBooleanButton id="token1" value="#{UserSession.getDisponibilitateGenerala(1)}"
        onLabel="Da" offLabel="Nu">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="dataTable" action="#{UserSession.toogleDisponibilitateGenerala(1, value)}"/>
    </p:selectBooleanButtom>
</p:column>
```